# Load satellite image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I've a problem about how can I load a Landsat image on Matlab. My image is in format .img and have the following information:

```
Columns and rows= 9487 x 8543
Number of bands= 6
Cellsize= 25 x 25
Source Type= continuous
Píxel type= unsigned integer
Pixel Depth= 16 bit
Scale factor= 0,9996
```

And this is my code:

> IM= multibandread('2000.img',[9487, 8543,
>   6],'int16',0,'ieee-le',{'Row','Range',[9487 8543]);

But there's the following error:

Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

I've tried to change but it doesn't work. What can I do?

Thanks in advance,

Emma

Comment: It appears you are missing a `}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dennis, but it's still not working!

Comment: Not sure if this is a problem, but I see that you are using int16 rather than the unsigned variant uint16. If this does not solve it, perhaps you could upload the image?

Answer (score 2):

Dennis is right, you're missing a closing curly brace. It should be inserted between the bracket and the parenthesis at the end like this:

> IM= multibandread('2000.img',[9487, 8543, 6],'int16',0,'ieee-le',{'Row','Range',[9487 8543]**}**);

Comment: Thank you! I've added it, but it doesn't work.   I receive the following error.??? Error using ==> fopen
Invalid machine format.

Error in ==>
multibandread>parseInputs at 317
fid =
fopen(filename,'r',byteOrder);

Error in ==> multibandread at 112
info = parseInputs(filename,
dims,...

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to leave the subset argument out completely, this in addition to using unsigned uint16, try the following:

```
multibandread('2000.img',[9487, 8543, 6],'uint16',0,'ieee-le')
```

Note that with your current call it appears that you are trying to extract row 9487 to 8543.